# format date depending on the locale in ngModel

Tags: angularjs, localization

Does angular localization provide this: Can the value format bound to ngModel change depending on the locale? I have an input control :

```
<input type="text" value={{from| date: 'shortDate'}} ng-model="from">
```

Currently the date is displayed in MM/dd/yyyy format. When i change the locale to German, the value bound to ngModel should update the format to TT/MM/JJJJ.
Should we write a filter for this? or Angular locale provides it?

Answer (score 1):

for all date filter
Have you seen https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date?

Comment: How can i use a filter with ngModel? an example will help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) it seems it does support

> Angular supports i18n/l10n for date, number and currency filters.

Comment: Yes, it does. My question was how do we format the value bound to ngModel depending on the locale?